# How to swap UI of a custom rom with other rom?

Tags: custom-roms, customization, system, user-interface

I have a custom rom which has Xperia like UI. It's very fast uses very less Ram. The other rom has Kitkat/Jellybean like UI but it has low performance as compared to Xperia UI like rom.

I was wondering if I could change UI of Xperia rom with the other Kitkat rom. is it possible?

I want to change Notification bar, menus , locker, Popup windows, buttons etc.

I use custom launcher and keyboard so no need to change that.

Comment: Xposed Framework will help .... Install it http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/versions-changelog-t2714053 Grab some modules http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/xposed-modules-android-rom/ and HOLLA you are the one with awsome phone ... 3;)
http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-customizing-statusbar-modding-apks-t2332575

Answer (score 0):

If your ROM has Theme Chooser integrated into the system, I would recommend just switching to an AOSP theme, like [this KitKat theme.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steel89ita.android44)

You can check if you have Theme Chooser by doing any of the below:

> *Android 2.3:* Check if there is an app in your launcher named 'Theme Chooser', with an icon of the Android robot colored four different colors
>
> *Android 4.0+:* Check if there is any theme-related menus in Settings.

If your ROM does not have Theme Chooser, then you would have to get your hands dirty with manually themeing system APKs. Go to [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com) for more info and tutorials on that.